# I'm having a problem with a loop in python

Tags: python, loops

So im trying to make a code that takes an number input from the user and with that input it will display a x number of other inputs to fill in data to be writed it down on a .txt file. But i can't really make it stop showing even with a `if x > f:` `break`.
Im still learning python and got this far with my little project.

```
f = file.write(input("Probes:"))
if f == 1:
    file.write(" One Single Soil Probe")
else:
    file.write(" Multiple Soil Probes")
file.write(" \n")

# System
x = 1
for a in range(f):
    file.write("SP" + str(x) + ": ")
    file.write(input("SP " + str(x) + ": " + " \n"))
    file.write("m")
    x = x + 1
    if f > x:
        break
    else:
        continue
file.write(" \n")

file.close()
```

Comment: You should get rid of x, and use the variable a. a will start at 0 and go up to the value of f I believe

Comment: The `input` function produces a string. So even if the user types in a number you need to convert it to a number.

Comment: comparison is not good. Also the range. Personally by looking at the code don't understand either how many iterations you need. Please explain

Comment: So mainly i want the user to input how many iterations he needs to input data

Exemple how i want it to run:
Probres: 2
SP 1: (put info here)
SP 2: (Put info here)

Close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the code as presented.

First of all, while `file.write` may return a number, it's not a useful number in this context: it returns the number of bytes written to the file.  SO that's the first change you need to make.

```
f = input("Probes:")
```

Howewver, `input` returns a string, so we need to convert that to a number.  If we ignore error checking, it's quite simple:

```
f = int(input("Probes:"))
```

Now we've lost the `file.write` call, so we need to add that back in.  However, `file.write` takes a string:

```
f = int(input("Probes:"))
file.write(str(f))
```

The next bit is OK now:

```
f = int(input("Probes:"))
file.write(str(f))

if f == 1:
    file.write(" One Single Soil Probe")
else:
    file.write(" Multiple Soil Probes")
file.write(" \n")
```

Next we have your processing loop.  You really shouldn't be combining reads and writes like that, it makes it difficult to understand what's going on.  I'd re-write it something like this:

```
for a in range(f):
    sp_val = input("SP " + str(a+1) + ": " + " \n")
    file.write("SP" + str(a+1) + ": " + sp_val + "m\n")
file.write(" \n")

file.close()
```

Then there's a couple of tricks you can use to make it even cleaner.  First is the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), secondly is [fstrings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```
with open(filename) as file:
    f = int(input("Probes:"))
    file.write(str(f))

    for a in range(f):
        sp_val = input(f"SP {a+1}:  \n")
        file.write(f"SP{a+1}: {sp_val}m\n")
    file.write(" \n")
```

The final point I'd make is to rename some of the variables to make it clearer what they do, and to avoid hiding builtin functions:

```
with open(filename) as ouput_file:
    probe_num = int(input("Probes:"))
    ouput_file.write(str(probe_num))

    for a in range(probe_num):
        sp_val = input(f"SP {a+1}:  \n")
        ouput_file.write(f"SP{a+1}: {sp_val}m\n")
    ouput_file.write(" \n")
```

Comment: Very interesting, but there's a little problem now that im recieving an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eng5\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\TxtFacil.py", line 39, in <module>
    file.write(f)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int

Comment: Good catch, I missed that.  Fixed.

Comment: Ty sir! U just teached me new stuff and made my 2 day struggle with this part to be over.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems start with this line:

```
f = file.write(input("Probes:"))
```

Firstly, [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) always returns a string, so if you want to compare it to integers later on you'd need to cast it using [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

However, the bigger problem is that you're not assigning the return value of the `input()` statement to `f`, you're assigning the return value of `file.write()`. Something like this will serve you better:

```
f = int(input("Probes:"))
file.write(f)
...
```

Also, as explained in the comments above, you don't need `x`, since you're already using `a`. Keep in mind, however, that [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#range) starts producing values at 0 unless told otherwise.